# How to define HTML xmlns for HTML 5?

Tags: asp.net-4.0

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

This is common for below HTML 5 standard.

In my application i have implemented HTML 5.

so what XML namespace have to be used? is this mandatory across browsers?

Help me guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for an xmlns declaration in an HTML5 document, unless you're using the XML serialisation, in which case `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` is still fine.